# Shared preference is taking wrong context

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

Hi I am saving my data by using **shared preference**.In my project have 2 Activities in Activity 1 I am saving data in `shared preference` inside of **asynctask** >> `doinBackground` method.In async task I am downloading multiple files from server.When my first file download started and I am changing Activities now my Activity-1 in background and My Activity-2 in foreground.My file is downloading in background my `sharedpreference` also calling in this time `SharedePreference` returns null context and it's giving nullpointer exception.

If Activity-1 in foreground I am not getting nullpointer exception.
Why it's returns null context if any other activity comes foreground?

My logcat :

```
02-18 06:45:55.503: W/System.err(1242): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-18 06:45:55.503: W/System.err(1242):     at info.helper.MyPreferences.savePreferences(MyPreferences.java:17)
02-18 06:45:55.503: W/System.err(1242):     at info.activity.DownloadActivity$DownloadFileFromURL.doInBackground(DownloadActivity.java:820)
02-18 06:45:55.503: W/System.err(1242):     at info.activity.DownloadActivity$DownloadFileFromURL.doInBackground(DownloadActivity.java:1)
02-18 06:45:55.503: W/System.err(1242):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-18 06:45:55.503: W/System.err(1242):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-18 06:45:55.503: W/System.err(1242):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-18 06:45:55.503: W/System.err(1242):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-18 06:45:55.503: W/System.err(1242):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
02-18 06:45:55.503: W/System.err(1242):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
02-18 06:45:55.503: W/System.err(1242):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-18 06:45:55.503: W/dalvikvm(1242): threadid=24: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa62b6288)
```

Edit #1

common method for saving application data :

```
public static void savePreferences(Context context, String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
            MY_ST_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Saving data inside AsyncTask like this:

```
 MyPreferences.savePreferences(DownloadActivity.this.getActivity(),
                        "downloading_storyid", downloadingStoryId);
```

Comment: Where is the code?? Add respective code here..

Comment: Save shared preference in post execute of asyn

Comment: Is your class extends with Fragment or FragmentActivity??

Comment: My DownloadActivity extends Fragment.

Comment: what is **MyPreferences**?

Comment: this is my custom class in this class i am creating common method for storing application data into shared preference.that above mention method is create inside of this MyPreferences class

Comment: Try to change SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(
            MY_ST_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: without context how we can create getSharedPreferences(String,int).If i create this it giving this error : The method getSharedPreferences(String, int) is undefined for the type StoryTimePreferences.

Comment: now what is **StoryTimePreferences**?

Comment: I forgot to edit that is MyPreferences.

Comment: i am getting exception when my first file downloading is completed and second one is come to downloading in this time DownloadingActivity(Activity 1) is not in foreground it's in background and Activity 2 in foreground.In this time it's taking null context.Why?

Comment: What is the line 17 at MyPreferences.java ?

Comment: SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
            MY_ST_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); this is that line

Answer (score 0):

since you are using context in asyntask , so it is pointing towards asyntask not activity. you have to pass context in asyntask like this :

`youractivityname.this ;`

Comment: Please check my Edit#1.My activity extends Fragment

Comment: why are you making it private. it is by default private.

Comment: Yes,It's taking by default int value 0(MODE_PRIVATE) instead of 0 i mentioned MODE_PRIVATE.It's any problem for mention this MODE_PRIVATE as per my issue?

Comment: try removing this SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
            MY_ST_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); and add

Comment: SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferecences(youtactivityname.this);

Comment: i am getting exception when my first file downloading is completed and second one is come to downloading in this time  DownloadingActivity(Activity 1) is not in foreground it's in background and Activity 2 in foreground.In this time it's taking null context.Why?